# Selecting a user's friend's events

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have these information : 
Table "Users" =>

```
 **Id**     **Name** 
   1           a
   2           b
   3           c
   4           d
   5           e
```

Table "Friends" =>

```
**SenderId**  **ReceiverId**    **State**
     1              2              x 
     2              3              ok 
     3              1              ok
     3              4              ok
     5              3              ok 
     5              4              ok
```

Table "Events" =>

```
     **SenderId**    **receiverId**     **text**
 1        1                3              ssss
 2        3                1             dsadsa
 3        2                3             safsdf
 4        3                5              fgfdgfd
 5        4                3             fgfhgfh
 6        5                4              sad sad
```

My question is that how could I get the events of user's friends in one sql statement using JOINS only .

for example :=>

- userId : 1
- his friends : 3 (state = ok)
- friends events : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5  (events from 1 to 5 have the userId 3 which considered as a friend to user 1 )

ANY HELP .. THANKS ;) !!

Comment: Do the events need to be displayed as a comma separated list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify a name for the first column in your `Events` table so I've called it `row_ID`:

```
SELECT U1.ID AS user_ID, U1.Name AS user_name, 
       U2.ID AS friend_user_ID, U2.Name AS friend_user_name, 
       E1.row_ID, E1.text AS event_text
  FROM Users AS U1
       INNER JOIN Friends AS F1
          ON (
              U1.ID = F1.ReceiverId
              OR U1.ID = F1.SenderId
             )
             AND F1.State = 'ok'
       INNER JOIN Users AS U2
          ON U2.ID = F1.SenderId
       INNER JOIN Events AS E1
          ON (
              U2.ID = E1.ReceiverId
              OR U2.ID = E1.senderId
             )
 WHERE U1.ID = 1;
```

Comment: very nice solution but => U1.SenderId not always equal to E1.SenderId it could be E1.ReceiverId ..!!

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure is quite confusing with all those Sender and Receiver ID's, but I think the following query will work.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT Users.Name, Events.text 
   FROM Users  
   LEFT JOIN Friends ON Users.Id = Friends.ReceiverId 
   LEFT JOIN Events ON Friends.SenderId = Events.SenderId 
   WHERE Users.Id = 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT Users.Name, Events.text 
   FROM Users 
   LEFT JOIN Friends ON Users.Id = Friends.ReceiverId 
   LEFT JOIN Events ON Friends.SenderId = Events.ReceiverId 
   WHERE Users.Id = 1)
```

You can probably simplify this, but I'm not sure how, considering you want to select events 1-5 because the friend ID can be either the Events.SenderId or the Events.ReceiverId.

I don't know if SQL supports this, but maybe put an `OR` into the `LEFT JOIN` clause (?):

```
SELECT Users.Name, Events.text 
  FROM Users 
  LEFT JOIN Friends ON Users.Id = Friends.ReceiverId 
  LEFT JOIN Events ON (Friends.SenderId = Events.SenderId OR Friends.SenderId  = Events.ReceiverId) 
  WHERE Users.Id = 1
```

Comment: I'm sorry but can u take a look at the first query again !!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy with a sub-query.

Here's the subquery (find user 1's friends)

```
SELECT
   senderID
FROM
   friends
WHERE
   receiverID = 1
```

Here's the main query (find user1's friend's events)

```
SELECT
   primary_key,
   senderID,
   receiverID,
   text
FROM
   events
WHERE
      senderID IN (subquery) --events where user1's friends were the senders
   OR receiverID IN (subquery) --events where user1's friend's were the receivers
```

Put it all together:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   events
WHERE
      senderID IN (SELECT
                      senderID
                   FROM
                      friends
                   WHERE
                      senderID = 1) --events where user1's friends were the senders
   OR receiverID IN (SELECT
                      senderID
                   FROM
                      friends
                   WHERE
                      receiverID = 1) --events where user1's friend's were the receivers
```

You might consider replacing the explicit '1' with a variable, so you can run this query for every user.

Good luck

Comment: I can do it with Subquery I need to do it with JOINS .. but thanx alot :)